# OTRS SQL BOX "Executing OS Commands"

Tags: mysql, otrs

How can I execute OS/Windows commands from within SQL Box present in the OTRS Admin panel. I tried too many formats but seems I am missing something in the syntax !

OTRS is installed on a windows Box and using MYSQL as a database

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You did not share what database you use with OTRS.
MySQL does not allow you to execute OS commands from within SQL statements.

Microsoft SQL Server does give you this possibility, although limited to the permissions of the service account:

```
EXECUTE [master].[dbo].[xp_cmdshell] 'dir c:\otrs'
```

for this to work your database account must have appropriate privileges, see also: [permission was denied on the object xp_cmdshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511658/permission-was-denied-on-the-object-xp-cmdshell)

Comment: Sorry for that. I forget to mention that it is MYSQL. Away from this, is there is any way that I can execute OS commands from within OTRS admin panel ?

Comment: No, not unless you'd write a frontend for this yourself.